# R data.frame to table image for presentation

Tags: r, image, dataframe

I have a data.frame df

```
 Name            Count
 Apples           12
 Oranges          22
 Bananas          14
```

Would like to convert this to a table like an image file so that I can use it in my presentation.

Comment: You mean like a literal image? Of the raw data? Or a plot of some sort?

Comment: Are you using Powerpoint? Beamer? Something else?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The most direct option is to probably use `grid.table` from the "gridExtra" package. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", it's as easy as doing:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.table(mydf)
```

which should yield something that looks like:

[image]