# Plotting Visual Tables

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a table in R and I am trying to format it so that is visually attractive for presentations.

I am trying to make it look like:

```
            2000-01-01    2000-03-01   2000-06-01 ...
Revenue       3.5           4.6            7.9

Cost          2.3           2.7            5.6
```

And have the boxes that encapsulate the words, numbers, be the right size such that the column header dates and row labels are not squished . How do I do that??

```
plot.table(t(z))

z <- structure(c(68.2, 66.1, 64.7, 31.8, 30.9, 25.4, 36.1, 38.3, 38.3, 
42.2, 43.3, 40.2, 41.9, 47.7, 50.8, 46.7, 48.2, 55.2, 58.2, 55.3, 
58.2, 62.5, 62.2, 59.5, 59.3, 59.4, 58.7, 68.2, 64.9, 94.7, 75.7, 
72, 73.5, 77.9, 83.8, 82.6, 83.8, 88.8, 91.5, 91.8, 92.6, 103.4, 
100.5, 110.8, 105.4, 113.5, 110, 110.2, 118.9, 125.5, 122.5, 
121.4, 122.6, 122.6, 127.4, 133.8, 131.5, 137.6, 142.7, 133, 
39.8, 46.3, 38.2, 16.6, 14.5, 17.4, 17.7, 19.1, 19, 21.2, 20.9, 
21.2, 19.9, 23.5, 25.2, 25.3, 23.3, 27.9, 29.3, 28.1, 29.6, 32.4, 
31.3, 31.1, 31.3, 31.3, 31.5, 36, 36.9, 40.1, 39, 37.4, 38.1, 
41.1, 43.1, 42.3, 42.4, 45.3, 46.4, 47.3, 48.2, 54.1, 51.6, 57.8, 
54.3, 59.7, 56.1, 56.1, 60.9, 65.8, 62.8, 62.8, 62.1, 63.8, 65.5, 
68.2, 66.7, 72.1, 75.1, 71.6), .Dim = c(60L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("11323", "11413", "11504", "11596", "11688", "11778", "11869", 
    "11961", "12053", "12143", "12234", "12326", "12418", "12509", 
    "12600", "12692", "12784", "12874", "12965", "13057", "13149", 
    "13239", "13330", "13422", "13514", "13604", "13695", "13787", 
    "13879", "13970", "14061", "14153", "14245", "14335", "14426", 
    "14518", "14610", "14700", "14791", "14883", "14975", "15065", 
    "15156", "15248", "15340", "15431", "15522", "15614", "15706", 
    "15796", "15887", "15979", "16071", "16161", "16252", "16344", 
    "16436", "16526", "16617", "16709"), c("revenue", "cost")))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R data.frame to table image for presentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558266/r-data-frame-to-table-image-for-presentation)

Comment: Well I know how to print the table into a visual table. My problem is how do I get the boxes to be the right size. When I try to plot the data, the box around each box is very large therefore only a handful of datapoints appear.

Comment: How are you presenting your table? `knitr`? `knitr::kable(z)` looks decent, but I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Where does plot.table come from?  This was online: # load Systematic Investor Toolbox
setInternet2(TRUE)
source(gzcon(url('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz', 'rb')))